# Set input value depending on selected value and store into db with php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, joomla3.0

I have a selection drop down and what I am trying to do is set two values into the db fields with a single selection after submitting the form. My drop down has values A1, A2, A3 which are inputted into a db field A. What I want to do is when I make a selection for A : A1, A2 or A3 then another field B should get the values B1, B2 or B3 accordingly i.e. when A = A1 then B = B1, when A = A2 then B = B2, when A = A3 then B = B3.
I tried establishing that using the the following code but what happens is when I select A1 for A then A gets A1 but B doesn't change value when I save/submit the form.
If I save the form again w/o any changes for A then A = A1 and changes from whatever its value was to B = B1, which is correct but it gets the correct value only when I save the form w/o changing my selection for A.
Now if I select A = A2 then B doesn't change value again it remains B1 (B = B1). If I select A = A3 then B changes to be B2 (B = B2) etc I think you got the point..... This way B is lets say "a selection behind".....
Here is my code:

```
<?php if( $this->item->A == 'A1'){ echo ($this->item->A);  echo ($this->item->B); ?>
<select name="A"><option value="A1" selected="selected">A1</option><option value="A2">A2</option><option value="A3">A3</option></select>
<input type="text" name="B" id="B" style="display:none;" value=B1>
<?php echo ($this->item->B); } 
elseif( $this->item->A == 'A2') { echo ($this->item->A); echo ($this->item->B); ?>
<select name="A"><option value="A1">A1</option><option value="A2" selected="selected">A2</option><option value="A3">A3</option></select>
<input type="text" name="B" id="B" style="display:none;" value=B2>
<?php echo ($this->item->B); }
elseif( $this->item->A == 'A3') { echo ($this->item->A); echo ($this->item->B); ?>
<select name="A"><option value="A1">A1</option><option value="A2">A2</option><option value="A3" selected="selected">A3</option></select>
<input type="text" name="B" id="B" style="display:none;" value=B3>
<?php echo ($this->item->B); }
else {?>
<select name="A"><option value="A1">A1</option><option value="A2" >A2</option><option value="A3">A3</option></select>
<?php } ?>
```

QUESTION: How is it possible when I make a selection for A : A1, A2 or A3 then B gets the values B1, B2 or B3 accordignly when I save the form? i.e. when A = A1 then B = B1, when A = A2 then B = B2, when A = A3 then B = B3?
Do I need to use JavaScript, jQuery?
I am not familiar with those and as you understood I am not a programmer....
Could you please show me the code I should use.
Please help.....

Answer (score 0):

you can do it like this

```
$('[name=A]').change(function(){
$('#B').val($(this).val());
});
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/136036/discussion-on-answer-by-john-ambrose-set-input-value-depending-on-selected-value).

Answer (score 0):

HTML should be something like this:

```
<select name='A'>
  <option data-input="B1" value='A1'>A1</option>
  <option data-input="B2" value='A2'>A2</option>
  <option data-input="B3" value='A3'>A3</option>
</select>
<input name='B'>
```

Include jQuery in your page header. And add following script.

```
    <script>   
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('select[name="A"]').change(function() {
                $('input[name="B"]').val($(this).find(':selected').data('input'));
            });
        });
    </script>
```

here is the fiddle: 
https://jsfiddle.net/merqe16e/1/

Comment: I added <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.1/jquery.min.js"></script> on to page and also your code below my code but except some errors I get into the chrome console it didn't work.... I am possibly doing it wrong. Could you send me the whole code? Thanks

Comment: I forgot to mention that A and B are db fields of the same record. Does this changes anything?

Comment: I think that jQuery is included into the page header. I see these lines : <script src="/media/jui/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script src="/media/jui/js/jquery-noconflict.js"></script> inside the <head></head> tags.... This is Joomla 3 backend file.....

Comment: you need to copy above inside your <body></body> tag just before </body>

Comment: Thanks for replying... In your fiddle when I select A1 then B gets A1.... If I understand correctly. What I want is when I select A1 for A to get B1 for B and not A1 for B.....

Answer (score 0):

I thank you very much all..... I finally got the answer to my problem by understanding from your answers and applying the following solution:

```
<select name='A'>
   <option data-input="B1" value='A1'>A1</option>
   <option data-input="B2" value='A2'>A2</option>
   <option data-input="B3" value='A3'>A3</option>
</select>
<input type="number" id="B" name='B'>

<script>   
   $(document).ready(function() {
   $('select[name="A"]').change(function() {
   $('input[name="B"]').val($(this).find(':selected').data('input'));
  });
});
</script>
```

but I adjusted it to my variables and it works like a charm ! ! !
I thank you very much again